# How does LWC HTML refer to the MAP value in JS?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

**JS Map Value**

```
@track currentSelectedProduct = '{"01t1s000000j70VAAQ":{"Id":"01t1s000000j70VAAQ","Name":"test","ProductCode":"200299060003","Number__c":"CRM-000001","MOQ__c":10,"StandardCost__c":10,"Description":"Test"}}'
```

**HTML Code**

```
<template>
        <div class="slds-box" if:true={showSelectedRecord}>
            <table class="slds-table">
                <tbody for:each={currentSelectedProduct} for:item="pro" key={pro.id}>
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-truncate" >{pro.Name}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</template>
```

I know that if "**currentSelectedProduct**" is a List, there will be no problem with this.
But "**currentSelectedProduct**" is a Map, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are likely need to make the object iterable to use it in `for:each` statement. To do that you can create a getter inside your class. Since the component will rerender each time the data is updated, the getter result will be updated as well. The easiest option would be to use `Object.entries` and then transform array `[key, value]` to object `{key: key, value: value}`. Please see the full code below.

```js
export default class extends LightningElement {
    @track currentSelectedProduct = '{"01t1s000000j70VAAQ":{"Id":"01t1s000000j70VAAQ","Name":"test","ProductCode":"200299060003","Number__c":"CRM-000001","MOQ__c":10,"StandardCost__c":10,"Description":"Test"}}'
    get currentSelectedProductList() {
        return Object.entries(this.currentSelectedProduct).map([key, value] => {key, value});
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
        <div class="slds-box" if:true={showSelectedRecord}>
            <table class="slds-table">
                <tbody for:each={currentSelectedProductList} for:item="pro" key={pro.key}>
                    <tr class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <td>
                            <div class="slds-truncate" >{pro.value.Name}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract the detail you want to present into a (tracked) array instead of a map. LWC template handling is quite unsophisticated and only provides array iteration with `template for:each`.

Comment: How would you do it ?